# MBP 16" i9 (Late 2019) Possibly Overheating

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, temperature

I just got a 2019 MBP 16" Model with 2.3 GHz i9 (turbo to 4.8GHz). When running simulations in MATLAB I have noticed the fans to spin quite loudly, and the CPU temp is rising very high. I have seen the temp peak 100C when plugged in, and around a max of 95C on battery power.

**My question** is whether this is typical behavior for this computer/CPU or whether I am at risk of damaging my components.

(Note: I am using this completely out of the box - have made no modifications, overclocking etc.. The temperatures I am seeing are just higher than I have seen previously for CPUs and I was shocked to be honest)

[image: Sample of Late 2019 MBP 16" i9 CPU temps when running on battery power]

Comment: This 'normal' behaviour is exactly why Apple are making their own CPUs that use less power and create less heat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPU is specified to function up to 100 degrees C. So a temperature of for example 95C is fully within its operational specification. There's no risk of damaging the CPU.

I.e. unless you experience some problem related to the temperature, there's absolutely nothing to worry about.

Comment: Sounds good thanks - through use the last few weeks I see the fans spinning up quite frequently when using all my engineering applications. I guess that is life with an i9 in a skinny laptop...